# "Make game out of something" meaning

Tags: meaning

I've been reading a sentence as follows

> The man carried the parcel in a funny way, he was actually **making a game out of carrying the parcel.**

I first thought the meaning is "Doing something in a funny, amusing way". But it was written at the starting of the sentence. Then, I found nothing so good on the web. I know the meaning of [make game of](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-game-of). Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"make game of X" is an entirely different expression than "making *a* game *(out) of* X" .

- "make game of X" , as your link suggests, makes X a subject/target of teasing/abuse.  (atlhough, as brought up in comments, I do not personally find that a commonly heard expression - though I think I would understand it that way - perhaps it's a turn of words from back when "handicap" meant more what it does in golf? )
- making ~*a*~ game ~ *(out) of* ~ X" .  ~transforms~ an activity into a game(as in a contest created for the purpose of amusement).  Informally the "out" might sometimes be omitted but it's meaning is still suggested.

Comment: I can’t speak for the British meaning but as an American I can say i’ve never heard of “make game of” to mean teasing or ridicule despite what Collins says. “Make *fun* of”, yes.

Comment: @Jim . I'm not saying it is common, but the OP did provide a link and suggested he was familiar with the term.  Yes "make fun of" is far more common to my ear, but there is also the similar contruct "make light of" .  I think 'game' might play more on the "quarry of a hunt" as in  "wild game". There is that aspect of the hunt which suggests done for diverting sport. I'd understand it that way even if I wouldn't use it myself.

Comment: but it is saying @Jim...it can't be wrong!...i love my collins